Where do I set sybsystem = com.domain to see log messages in XCode?
I integrated some Advertising SDK into my iOS app and trying to debug it.
To view their log message in the console in XCode I need to set sybsystem = com.yandex.mobile.ads.sdk. Where should I do that? Should I type this somewhere? O select this from some drop-down list?
My XCode screenshot:

There should be messages containing Yandex, but I do not see them.
My Xcode version: 15.4
